# How to get Slicer to multi select instead of multi DEselect?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Adjusting the multi select setting on my slicer makes it deselect items. However, I'd like to select multiple filters instead. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all items in a slicer are selected and you turn on multi-select, clicking a slicer item will de-select it and leave the others selected.

If you don't want that, turn off multi-select. Then click one slicer item. Then turn on multi-select and you can click additional slicer items.

Or, don't bother with the multi-select icon at all.  Select one slicer item, then hold down the Ctrl key to select non-adjacent slicer items, or hold down the Shift key to select from the current to the clicked slicer items.

In the animated screenshot below, a, c, and e are selected holding the Ctrl key. The selection of b to d is done with the Shift key held down. Note that the multi select option is not used at all.

[image]